Safely embedding third-party websites in an iframe on my site
There is a parent site (my site) and a child site (a third-party site that I want to embed in an iframe). I want to open the child site inside an iframe on my parent site.
I'm concerned that the child site, opened in an iframe, may be able to access information about my parent site, such as the URL, page title, cookies, and other data. I want to avoid any data leakage from my site.
What methods can I use to safely embed a third-party site in an iframe on my site, without allowing access to the data of my site?
I have studied the issue and understand that the site in the iframe can access information about the parent site.

Some sites take a dim view of other sites using their content in an iframe or deep linking to their hosted content. Their logs will show your site as the referrer. Some third parties will react by or ignoring the request or putting up a banner saying "stolen from original site" if the link to fetch their content is not from an end user, one of their domains or a recognised web spider. It can never really be safe for your users since the third party can control what your site is displaying in the iframe that you have given it.

You don’t need to do anything, the browser security model takes cares of this for you.
